# How to convert a blob column type clob to blob in db2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have a table in  DB2 with column type CLOB, I would like to convert this to a BLOB type. My approach here is to create a new column with BLOB type, copy all the data from CLOB column to BLOB column, drop the CLOB column and rename the BLOB column. However, I am not sure how to do the second step i.e. update data from CLOB column to BLOB column. What is the function of DB2 that will let me do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the Db2-server operating-system (z/os, i-series, linux/unix/windows)  and what's the Db2-version ?

Comment: I am using DB2 version 11.1.2.2 with oslevel 7.1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

As you are on Db2-LUW V11.1 and AIX, you can consider using the stored procedure **ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE** to do the work on-line. Test carefully on development and testing environments before promoting to production. 
Generally, it is easier to use the stored procedure than to do it manually, especially if you are learning, although you need SQLADM or DBADM rights, and carefully study the documentation.

One important detail is that you should ensure your table stores its data, index(es), and LONG data in *separate* tablespaces. That is best practice and applies regardless of which method you choose to implement.

See the ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE documentation at: 
[https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0055069.html](http://ADMIN_MOVE_TABLE)

If you don't want to use the stored procedure, you can also do it manually, although the method you choose may differ according to the number-of-rows in table *and* average-length-of-CLOB-column.

For tiny row-counts with small average-length-of-CLOB column:

```
- add the blob column with appropriate size to the table (alter table ... add column )
- populate the new column with an UPDATE statement set blobcolumn = blob(clobcolumn).
- alter table ... drop column clobcolumn
- offline reorg table
- runstats
```

For non-trivial row counts or large CLOBS

```
- create a new dedicated LONG tablespace if necessary
- create a new table, with the required blob column, and without the clob column, ensuring the LONG IN clause specifies correct tablespace
- declare a cursor for SELECT from oldtable , using BLOB(clobcolumn)
- use load from cursor to populate the new table
- runstats new table
- drop old table
- rename new table to be same as old table.
```

Comment: Thanks mao. Yes I can also use the CAST function to do this. Now I have another requirement, How do I do the reverse i.e converting a BLOB column type to CLOB. It looks like the above steps doesnt work for it.

Comment: Use a new question for a new problem , so do not ask new questions in comment threads. Consider marking answers as correct or upvoting answers that are helpful.

Comment: Thanks Mao. I have upvoted your answer since I found it useful

Answer (score 0):

you can't directly change the column type in your Db2 table from CLOB to BLOB!!
The ALTER `TABLE ALTER COLUMN SET DATA TYPE` statement allows changing columns of the following data types only:
Character
Numeric
Binary

Answer (score -2):

I think you can directly change the column type in your `Db2` table:

```
ALTER TABLE {TABLE NAME} ALTER COLUMN {COLUMN NAME} SET DATA TYPE BLOB({SIZE})
```

`CLOB` is very similar to `BLOB`, main difference is that CLOB is used to store large textual contents(which have character encoding info), `BLOB` is just a long binary string(e.g. a binary file).

Comment: Unfortunately My DB2 database doesn't let me do this. The Alter statement fails with reason that the new column type is not compatible with existing column.