# how to convert a blob column type to clob in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have a table in DB2 with column type BLOB, I would like to convert this to a CLOB type. My approach here is to create a new column with CLOB type, copy all the data from BLOB column to CLOB column, drop the BLOB column and rename the CLOB column. However, I am not sure how to do the second step i.e. update data from BLOB column to CLOB column. How can I do this in DB2. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a blob column type clob to blob in db2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48974066/how-to-convert-a-blob-column-type-clob-to-blob-in-db2)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Db2-LUW v10.5 or higher, consider using the supplied [stored procedure **CONVERTTOCLOB**](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0055119.html) for that purpose. Such a conversion makes sense when you know the data is character based.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CONVERTTOCLOB` stored procedue, but if you want to convert a BLOB to a CLOB within a query, and you don't mind it being truncated to 32K bytes, then you can use `VARCHAR()` to convert it. Here follows an example

```
create table b(b blob) organize by row;
insert into b values blob(x'F09F9880');
select cast(VARCHAR(b) as VARCHAR(4) FOR MIXED DATA) from b;

1   
----
```

Note the `CAST( ... as VARCHAR(x) FOR MIXED DATA)` bit converts from a `VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA` so the output is not shown in hex format